# why is it the fancybox not getting closed even if my page has the code to close

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is the code of parent page which is used to load an external page from a remote domain, but when I click on the close link in the iframe page it is not getting closed. Could anyone guide me, where am I going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'http://2792.a.hostable.me/testing/instagram/tester.php',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5 
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a id="fancybox-manual-b" href="javascript:;">Open single item, custom options</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in the remote page is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - iframe demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>fancyBox - iframe demo</h1>

    <p>
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();">Close me</a>

        |

        <a href="javascript:parent.document.returnval('asdf');">return some value</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque justo ac eros consectetur bibendum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla aliquam turpis et tellus elementum luctus. Duis sit amet rhoncus velit. Duis nisl ligula, mattis interdum blandit laoreet, mattis id ante. Cras pulvinar lacus vitae nisi egestas non euismod neque bibendum. Vestibulum faucibus libero id ante molestie ultricies. Vestibulum quis nibh felis. Vestibulum libero nisl, vehicula vel ullamcorper sit amet, tristique sit amet augue. Etiam urna neque, porttitor sed sodales lacinia, posuere a nisl. Vestibulum blandit neque in sapien volutpat ac condimentum sapien auctor. Ut imperdiet venenatis ultricies. Phasellus accumsan, sem eu placerat commodo, felis purus commodo ipsum, sit amet vulputate orci est viverra est.
    </p>

    <p>
        Aenean velit est, condimentum ut iaculis ut, accumsan at mi. Maecenas velit mi, venenatis ut condimentum at, ultrices vel tortor. Curabitur pharetra ornare dapibus. Ut volutpat cursus semper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec eu iaculis ipsum. Morbi eu dolor velit, a semper nunc.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you are opening will also need the fancybox JS references otherwise it will not be able to recognise the code that is trying to close itself.

If you are using a modern browser, you should have access to a console (usually F12 will open this) which should display any JS errors.

Comment: that is not necessarily true; actually the opened page may have `<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();">close me</a>` only and still it will close fancybox.

Comment: i got the following error report in console of the chrome browser,

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://2792.a.hostable.me/testing/instagram/fancybox/demo/ from frame with URL http://fancyapps.com/demo/iframe.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
iframe.html:1Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined
(anonymous function)tester.php:1

Comment: definitively a Same Origin Policy issue

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me, however you should consider the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) when working with iframes.

When you try to close the page, it triggers this error

```
Timestamp: 08/07/2012 3:50:25 AM
Error: Permission denied to access property '$'
Source File: javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();
Line: 1
```

which it means that it may exist restrictions on that host to execute scripts from a different domain.

If you test locally or the two pages exist on the same server (same domain) then it will work seamlessly.